# Context error when converting react javascript navbar to typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to make a navbar like this one: https://pras75299-stripeweb.netlify.app/

The repo of the site above is here: https://github.com/pras75299/React-Stripewebsite

I have made a stack blitz of my attempt to convert it to typescript here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-tailwind-digital-clock-9hzwhn?file=context.tsx

In the context.tsx file, on line 70, I am getting an error here:

```
setPage(page);
```

when I am setting the state of 'page'. I don't know exactly what to decalre the type of page and so I've kept its type as 'any'.
This is the error I am getting:

```
Argument of type '{ page: string; links: { label: string; icon: "string" | "number" | "bigint" | "boolean" | "symbol" | "undefined" | "object" | "function"; url: string; }[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<{ page: string; links: { page: string; links: any[]; }; }>'.
  Type '{ page: string; links: { label: string; icon: "string" | "number" | "bigint" | "boolean" | "symbol" | "undefined" | "object" | "function"; url: string; }[]; }' is not assignable to type '{ page: string; links: { page: string; links: any[]; }; }'.
```

How can I fix this?

Would appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Typescript is helpfully telling you that you're trying to set `page` to this object

```js
{
    page: 'products',
    links: [
      { label: 'payment', icon: typeof FaCreditCard, url: '/products' },
      { label: 'terminal', icon: typeof FaCreditCard, url: '/products' },
      { label: 'connect', icon: typeof FaCreditCard, url: '/products' },
    ],
  }
```

But `page` expects this object

```js
  {
    page: '',
    links: { page: '', links: [] },
  }
```

So you'll want to set page to

```js
// I'm just assuming values for both page key values
setPage({ page: page.page, links: { page: page.page, links: page.links }})
```

For reference, if you want to check what state expects to be passed in you can hover over `setPage`.